# Java: String, Char, If, Error

Tags: java

I am having trouble making a file, I think I have got the majority of it correct, but I'm having trouble getMorseCode() method. I am almost positive it begins with

```
String morse = "";
```

however, since letter is a char and morse is a string, it results in an error. Otherwise it complies but simply returns a space when I run the tester I'm not sure what to put in the quotation marks though, can anyone give me a hint please?

Thanks,

```
public class MorseCode
{
    private char letter;

    public MorseCode(char let)
    {
    letter = let;

    }

    public char getLetter()
    {
        return letter;

    }

    public String getMorseCode()
    {
        String morse = "";
            if (morse.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
                morse = ".-";







        return morse;
    }

}

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A class to test the MorseCode class
 */
public class MorseCodeTester
{
    /**
     * Tests methods of the MorseCode class
     * @param args not used
     */
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        char morseChar = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        MorseCode one = new MorseCode(morseChar);
        System.out.println(one.getLetter() + " is " + one.getMorseCode() + " in morse!\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit : misread the question, `String morse = Character.toString(letter);` is what you need. (Assuming you want to use your current code)

In any case, you should just conduct a switch statement on the char instead, i.e

```
String morse = "";
switch(letter) {
            case 'a' :
            morse = ".-";
            break;
} //and so on
```

The problem with your current code is that morse is just being set to "" and you are testing cases against it, in which it will always evaluate false.

Comment: I deleted my answer 'cause I was typing faster than I was thinking. I noticed that letter was a char too late :)

Comment: Haha, it happens to the best of us :p.

Answer (score 0):

Replace that last bit of code in the main method

```
System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
char morseChar = morse.charAt(0); // <-----
MorseCode one = new MorseCode(morseChar);
```

And also with this part, I thought that when you were using single characters, you didn't use "a", you used 'a' instead? so try this... I'm not 100% sure about this so it may not work...

```
  if (morse.equalsIgnoreCase('a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually checking the letter in your method.
What you want to do is this: `String morse = ""+letter;` now you are actually testing the letter.
Java will turn chars and most numbers into strings when you add them onto an existing string, it's a nifty and easy way to turn numbers and chars into strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `morse = "";` this will always return nothing when you run test cases.

```
String morse = "";
switch (letter)
    {
        case 48 : morse = "- - - - -"; break;
        case 49 : morse = ". - - - -"; break;
        case 50 : morse = ". . - - -"; break;
        case 51 : morse = ". . . - -"; break;
        case 52 : morse = ". . . . -"; break;
        case 53 : morse = ". . . . ."; break;
        case 54 : morse = "- . . . ."; break;
        case 55 : morse = "- - . . ."; break;
        case 56 : morse = "- - - . ."; break;
        case 57 : morse = "- - - - ."; break;
        case 65 : morse = ". -"; break;
        case 66 : morse = "- . . ."; break;
        case 67 : morse =  "- . - ."; break;
        case 68 : morse = "- . ."; break;
        case 69 : morse = "."; break;
        case 70 : morse = ". . - ."; break;
        case 71 : morse = "- - ."; break;
        case 72 : morse = ". . . ."; break;
        case 73 : morse = ". ."; break;
        case 74 : morse = ". - - -"; break;
        case 75 : morse = "- . -"; break;
        case 76 : morse = ". - . ."; break;
        case 77 : morse = "- -"; break;
        case 78 : morse = "- ."; break;
        case 79 : morse = "- - -"; break;
        case 80 : morse = ". - - ."; break;
        case 81 : morse = ". - - ."; break;
        case 82 : morse = "- - . -"; break;
        case 83 : morse = ". - ."; break;
        case 84 : morse = ". . ."; break;
        case 85 : morse = "-"; break;
        case 86 : morse = ". . -"; break;
        case 87 : morse = ". . . -"; break;
        case 88 : morse = ". - -"; break;
        case 89 : morse = "- . . -"; break;
        case 90 : morse = "- . - -"; break;
        case 91 : morse = "- - . ."; break;
    }
    return morse;
```

This covers the ASCII values for all letters. Does this make sense now?